# Flask jsonify returns Response. How to provide status code?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful, flask-marshmallow, jsonify

I sow a lot of examples where developers have the following expression:

```
return jsonify(data), 200
```

Even in my last work project I had the same expression, but now, when I'm trying to write my new project, I catch the following error:

**TypeError:** Object of type Response is not JSON serializable

If I return only the result of `jsonify()`, it works but returns the 200 status code. I want to control the code. It doesn't work with `flask_restful.Resource`.

Seems like `jsonify()` returns `Response` object. How to fix it?

Comment: try it without jsonify(), flask-restful handles this already

Comment: Like this: `return data, 200`

Comment: yes, this is better.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, and ended up applying [Dzianis Talkachou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11437655/dzianis-talkachou)'s workaround to prevent it:

Wrapping the `jsonify` response in a `make_response` will do the trick.

```
from flask import jsonify, make_response
...
return make_response(jsonify(your_data), 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `data` is a Response object, and the code is choking when you try to serialize that into JSON. Try `return jsonify(data.text), 200`.

If that doesn't work, we need more code to diagnose this.

Comment: `data` it's example. If we pass types that JSON supports, result will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

flask-restful uses jsonify already.

if you use jsonify with flask-restful, it tries to jsonify a response twice.

simply do this:

```
return data, 200
```

Comment: It won't work with other objects like `datetime.date`
I found a solution. I wrapped it in `make_response`. Now it looks `make_response(jsonify(data), 200))`

Comment: turning the data to a json-compatible format is not the issue of this question, but I'm glad you found a way to make it work

Comment: it will be nice if you provide your ways, I want to find the better one

Comment: well you can simply turn the date object into a string by calling str(date), but like I said, that has nothing to do with this question.